# Visual Studio Code - definición del código

Tags: visual-studio-2017

uso ***Visual Studio Code*** en un equipo de escritorio y se ve correctamente, pero en el portátil las letras se ven pixeladas, le falta resolución y es muy incomodo de usar. Utilizo también sublime en este equipo y no tengo este problema, ¿hay alguna configuración o un modo de resolverlo?

Answer (score 0):

Intenta haciendo esto lo que se muestra en la imagen que adjunto, también puedes revisar esta publicación que en su momento me ayudo con el mismo problema.

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/1896

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Uso W7, no me aparecen esas opciones. Ya ví el hilo que indicas antes de poner la pregunta. Mi pantalla en realidad es más pequeña y mas q un difuminado es como si las letras se dibujarán más "pobres", en plan ahorro de recursos.